Cmake link with static runtime library
I need to compile executable with static runtime library for compilers msvc, gcc, clang. For msvc I do and it completely work
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")

For mingw gcc I do
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"

And with this I still have dependency of msvcrt.dll
For clang I do
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static"

With this I still have a lot of dependencies.
So what is the best solution to get rid of all dependencies?

So what is the best solution to get rid of all dependencies? Write a CMake module containing a cmake function that you include with all of your projects.

BTW, for msvc there is a target property: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html

The problem is still not solved. I don't know why cmake adds flags for clang to build executable with dynamic runtime library(-D_DLL flags for compiler and some flags for linker that I don't know how to disable)
